# flutter tflite object detection not working on physical device

Tags: flutter, object, detection

object detection only works on emulator device not on physical device

this exception only comes when using physical device
and works fine on emulator

```
const String ssd = 'SSD MobileNet';

class Object extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_ObjectState createState() => _ObjectState();
}

class _ObjectState extends State<Object> {
double _imageWidth;
double _imageHeight;
File _image;
bool _busy = false;
List _recognitions;
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  loadTfModel();
}

void loadTfModel() async {
  Tflite.close();
  try {
    await Tflite.loadModel(model: "assets/Models/ssd_mobilenet.tflite", labels: "assets/Models/labels.txt");
  } on PlatformException {
    print("faild to Load Models");
  }
}

void getImageFromGallary() async {
  var pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  if (pickedFile == null) return;
  _image = File(pickedFile.path);
  setState(() {
    _busy = true;
  });
  detectObject(_image);
}

detectObject(File image) async {
  if (image == null) return;
  ssdMobileNet(image);

  FileImage(image)
      .resolve(ImageConfiguration())
      .addListener((ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
        setState(() {
          _imageWidth = info.image.width.toDouble();
          _imageHeight = info.image.height.toDouble();
        });
      })));

  setState(() {
    _image = image;
    _busy = false;
  });
}

ssdMobileNet(File image) async {
  var recognitions = await Tflite.detectObjectOnImage(
      path: image.path, numResultsPerClass: 1);

  setState(() {
    _recognitions = recognitions;
  });
}

List<Widget> renderBoxes(Size screen) {
if (_recognitions == null) return [];
if (_imageWidth == null || _imageHeight == null) return [];

double factorX = screen.width;
double factorY = _imageWidth / _imageHeight * screen.width;

return _recognitions.map((re) {
  return Positioned(
    left: re["rect"]["x"] * factorX,
    top: re["rect"]["y"] * factorY,
    width: re["rect"]["w"] * factorX,
    height: re["rect"]["h"] * factorY,
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: 3,
      )),
      child: Text(
        "${re["detectedClass"]} ${(re["confidenceInClass"] * 100).toStringAsFixed(0)}%",
        style: TextStyle(
          background: Paint()..color = Colors.blue,
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 15,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}).toList();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var widthS = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  var heightS = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

List<Widget> stackChildren = [];

stackChildren.add(Positioned(
  top: 0.0,
  left: 0.0,
  width: size.width,
  child: _image == null ? Text("No Image Selected") : Image.file(_image),
));

stackChildren.addAll(renderBoxes(size));

if (_busy) {
  stackChildren.add(Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  ));
}

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Object detetction"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.image),
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    tooltip: "Pick an Image",
    onPressed: getImageFromGallary,
  ),
  body: Stack(
    children: stackChildren,
  ),
);
}
}
```

this is the exception i get

```
E/flutter ( 2827):  at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.onMethodCall(TflitePlugin.java:95)
E/flutter ( 2827):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter ( 2827):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/flutter ( 2827):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/flutter ( 2827):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 2827):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
E/flutter ( 2827):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/flutter ( 2827):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
E/flutter ( 2827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 2827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
E/flutter ( 2827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
E/flutter ( 2827):
F/flutter ( 2827): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(942)] Check failed: CheckException(env).
F/libc    ( 2827): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2827 (.asfandyr380.ai)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/a5ltexx/a5lte:6.0.1/MMB29M/A500FXXS1CRJ2:user/release-keys'
Revision: '10'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 2827, tid: 2827, name: .asfandyr380.ai  >>> com.asfandyr380.ai <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(942)] Check failed: CheckException(env).
'
    r0 00000000  r1 00000b0b  r2 00000006  r3 b6fd0b94
    r4 b6fd0b9c  r5 b6fd0b4c  r6 00000000  r7 0000010c
    r8 bed06b7c  r9 bed06c90  sl 00000001  fp b6f6fe3a
    ip 00000006  sp bed06b00  lr b6d50efd  pc b6d532f8  cpsr 400f0010
backtrace:
    #00 pc 000442f8  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01 pc 00041ef9  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
    #02 pc 0001ba13  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03 pc 00018c81  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
    #04 pc 00016840  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05 pc 000127c3  /data/app/com.asfandyr380.ai-2/lib/arm/libflutter.so
```

can anyone tell me why is this happening
i think this happens when i load models because if i remove the that part the app works fine but then the object detection cant work because the models are not loaded

Answer (score 0):

Hi there try out few steps for the flutter_tflite package try out the example code from https://pub.dev/packages/tflite/example
If it's working in the emulator and not on your device try out the code on some other device. Thanks